# Won't Create Temp txt file

Tags: java, txt

I would like to create a temporary txt file for my program. In the code below, "student1.txt" is a txt file that has already created but for "temporarystudent.txt" is is not. I have tried to run with Line 6 (while in Line 7 & 8 in comment) as well as  Line 7 & 8 (while Line 6 in comment) but neither of them are able to create "temporarystudent.txt". When I run the program, it didn't show any error neither in VS Code Terminal nor in the Program Output. It just won't create the "temporarystudent.txt". May I know what's wrong here?

```
    try
    {   
      //Locate the file.
      File file = new File("student1.txt");
      //Create a temporary file
      //File temp = File.createTempFile("temporarystudent", ".txt", file.getParentFile());
      File temp = new File("temporarystudent.txt");
      temp.createNewFile();
      //Determine the charset.
      String charset = "UTF-8";
      //Open the file for reading.
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), charset));
      //Open the temp file for writing.
      PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(temp), charset));
      //Read the file line by line.
      for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
        line = line.replace("null\n", "");
        writer.println(line);   
      }

      //Close the reader and writer (preferably in the finally block).
      reader.close();
      writer.close();
      //Delete the file.
      file.delete();
      //Rename the temp file.
      temp.renameTo(file);
      
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("An error occurred.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: given the fact most sdks already have built in temp folder/file creating functions, your question had better remove the `temp` keyword.

Comment: @LeiYang `temp` is not a keyword

Comment: isn't Temp a keyword in the title? it will let readers thinking of sdk's built in temp file creating functions.

Comment: The `temporarystudent.txt` **is** getting created and filled with `student1.txt` data. You just can't see the file because ... the `student1.txt` file is deleted with: `file.delete();` and the `temporarystudent.txt` file it is renamed right away with: `temp.renameTo(file);`. You will never see this file unless you step through your code with a debugger and look at the local file system before the file is renamed or an exception occurs before the rename happens. If you want to see this temp file then don't delete the `student1.txt` file and don't rename the temp file.